# Accessing aws cli from a private network

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

do you know where I can find a comprehensive list of IPs that need to be whitelisted in order to be able to use AWS CLI?

The scenario: I have my orchestrator server on an on-prem server without access to the internet, I can access the internet by asking networking folks to whitelist endpoints. I need to be able to fire aws cli commands from this private server, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides their public ips here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html .

I don't think the list is static so I would write a script to fetch the IPs. It should propably work only to whitelist the IPs for the region you are intending to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking this, I think It's what you are looking for:

[AWS service endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

As these update frequently, a quick google search for AWS service endpoints will get latest results

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/448670)

Comment: @DaveM Thank you for the feedback. In this case I chose that because the link lists AWS endpoints and the content, if copied here, will become outdated before the link disappear. I think that I can add the information to just Google !AWS service endpoints" to get updated results...